# CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh not always firing at app startup

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Visual Studio for Windows.

The CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh is not firing around 1/3 of the time at app startup.

This is the case in both debug and after deploying to device and running off of the device.

The code is as below.

Thanks

Regards

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += Current_OnTokenRefresh;
    }

    private void Current_OnTokenRefresh(object source, FirebasePushNotificationTokenEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Token: {e.Token}");
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyApp", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public partial class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        partial void OnPreCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            this.OnPreCreate(savedInstanceState);

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            LoadApplication(new App());

            this.OnPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Application.cs in Android project root folder

```
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : Application
    {
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                //Change for your default notification channel id here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";

                //Change for your default notification channel name here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";

                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelImportance = NotificationImportance.High;
            }

            //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
#endif

            //Handle notification when app is closed here
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to fire every time? I'm not an expert on Firebase push notifications, but it's my understanding that it will only be called when the token changes. Generally, the token doesn't change often after the token is assigned to the device as long as you're not clearing the app data / cache or reinstalling the application.

Comment: For what it's worth, we had some issues in the past with device tokens on Android, and we couldn't rely on the token refresh method to be called reliably even when the token had changed. We never could determine exactly what was going on, but we'd have times where a user would sign in to their application and the token we expected them to have is not what Firebase was saying they had. So we had to adopt a system of always double checking the token on sign in and updating our records as needed to reflect any changes to the device token.